# Could not find module 'PromiseKit' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator,

Tags: xcode, build, apple-m1, swift-package-manager

> Could not find module 'PromiseKit' for target
> 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator,
> at:
> /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...-fegumwieafhctvflusomkxujrdgf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromiseKit/PromiseKit.framework/Modules/PromiseKit.swiftmodule

Xcode 13.0, Apple M1 laptop.
Dependency was added by SPM.
Adding arm64 to excluded architectures didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: did you find this questions answer?